# Can you rename a table to the new database when restoring from a .bak file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore

So I've almost wrote all of the SQL code I have to restore from a backup file from sql 2008 to 2016. Problem is, one of the tables called Students has the same table structure in the old db and the new db (I'm restoring to a new database too), but in the old db, Students is name Stdnents. Is there ANY way I can restore correctly?

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='f:\newBDbackup.bak'

declare @DefaultData nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', @DefaultData output

declare @DefaultLog nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', @DefaultLog output

declare @DefaultBackup nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'BackupDirectory', @DefaultBackup output

declare @MasterData nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters', N'SqlArg0', @MasterData output
select @MasterData=substring(@MasterData, 3, 255)
select @MasterData=substring(@MasterData, 1, len(@MasterData) - charindex('\', reverse(@MasterData)))

declare @MasterLog nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters', N'SqlArg2', @MasterLog output
select @MasterLog=substring(@MasterLog, 3, 255)
select @MasterLog=substring(@MasterLog, 1, len(@MasterLog) - charindex('\', reverse(@MasterLog)))

select 
    isnull(@DefaultData, @MasterData) DefaultData, 
    isnull(@DefaultLog, @MasterLog) DefaultLog,
    isnull(@DefaultBackup, @MasterLog) DefaultBackup

declare @NewDefaultData nvarchar(512)
select isnull(@NewDefaultData, CONVERT(nvarchar(512), @DefaultData))
declare @NewDefaultLog nvarchar(512)
select isnull(@NewDefaultLog, CONVERT(nvarchar(512), @DefaultLog)) 

RESTORE DATABASE NewSqlDatabase FROM DISK='f:\newBDbackup.bak'
WITH
    MOVE 'newDatabase' TO @NewDefaultData,
    MOVE 'newDatabase_log' TO @NewDefaultLog
```

Comment: Maybe you can work around it. Create a new instance of the database(with the old Stdnents table name), restore from the backup with the incorrect table name, then do an insert statement from Stdnents to Students

Comment: How would the Insert statement work?

Comment: It would be something like:

USE TargetDb
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Students(field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.Stdnents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the issue but can you not simply rename the table "Stdnents" to "Students" immediately after the restore (sp_rename)

Comment: But wouldn't the restore fail? Because the tables in the old db are all the same as the new db, just one is named wrong

Comment: (S)he means that you can rename the table "Students" to "Stdnents" in your current database, restore from the backup, then re-rename the table back to students.